# Existe o formato "dd-mmm-yyyy" (por exemplo, "13-fev-1980") no R?

Tags: r

Gostaria de saber se existe o formato "yyyy-MES ABREVIADO-dd"

Exemplo:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

df<-data.frame(dt=c("1980-02-13", "1983-08-03"))
df

          dt
1 1980-02-13
2 1983-08-03
```

Eu consigo colocar o mês abreviado separando as colunas:

```
df2<-df %>% 
  mutate(dt=ymd(dt),
         ano=year(dt),
         mes=month(dt, abbr = T, label = T))

          dt  ano mes
1 1980-02-13 1980 fev
2 1983-08-03 1983 ago
```

No entanto, gostaria de saber se exista alguma maneira de gerar uma saída do seguinte tipo:

```
dt
1 1980-fev-13
2 1983-ago-03
```

É possível ou estou equivocado?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dados da [resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/469210/82237) do usuário @neves.
Em uma linha de R base, veja os formatos [aqui](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/strptime.html).

```
format(as.Date(df$dt), "%d-%b-%Y")
#[1] "13-fev-1980" "03-ago-1983"
```

Se a coluna já for de classe `"Date"`, ver no fim da resposta, basta usar o `format`.

```
format(df$dt, "%d-%b-%Y")
#[1] "13-fev-1980" "03-ago-1983"
```

**Dados**

```
df <-
structure(list(dt = structure(c(3695, 4962), class = "Date")), 
row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 4):

Com `tidyverse`:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

df %>% 
  mutate(across(.cols = dt, .fns = ~ str_to_lower(month(., abbr = T, 
  label = T)), .names = "mes")) %>% 
  separate(col = dt, into = c('year', 'month', 'day'), sep = "-") %>% 
  unite(col = "dt", year, mes, day, sep = "-") %>% 
  select(-month)

           dt
1 1980-fev-13
2 1983-ago-03
```

Para obter a data no formato `dd//mm//yyyy` é só ajustar a linha seguinte:

```
separate(col = dt, into = c('day', 'month', 'year'), sep = "-")

           dt
1 13-fev-1980
2 03-ago-1983
```